# jquery addClass can`t find css class

Tags: jquery, css, addclass

Hy! I have a Click Event on my Odds DIV which should edit my Background Color, Fonts etc of odd, name and value div!!

The change for the odd div works, but not the child divs!!!

```
    <div class="oddspanel ui-grid-a">
        <div class="description ui-block-a">
            Description
        </div>
        <div class="odd ui-block-b">
            <div class="name">
                Name
            </div>
            <div class="value">
                1,40
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

and this is my Script Code:

```
    $(".odd").click(function(){
        $(this).removeClass("odd").addClass("odd-active");
        $(this).children(".name").removeClass("name").addClass("name-active");
        $(this).children(".value").removeClass("value").addClass("value-active");
    });
```

my CSS Code:

```
.odd .name {
width: 100%;
height: 15px;
line-height: 15px;
text-align: center;
font-size: x-small;
color: white;
 }

.odd .value {
width: 100%;
height: 25px;
line-height: 25px;
text-align: center;
color: #FFFF66;
  }

.odd .name-active {
 width: 100%;
 height: 15px;
 line-height: 15px;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: x-small;
 color: #9a9a9a;
 }

.odd .value-active {
width: 100%;
height: 25px;
line-height: 25px;
text-align: center;
color: #000000;
}
```

if I delete the .odd before for example .value-active it works !!! But i would like to put this as child in .odd in css!!!

Comment: Can you create a JSFiddle for this

Comment: in your css no odd-active class

Comment: i have an odd-active class ;) its not here because it works fine!

Comment: you could use only the css classes: [.odd .name] [.odd .value] [.odd-active .name] [.odd-active .value] ... after you remove .odd and add .odd-active, there is no need to have value-active or name-active

Answer (score 3):

Since `odd` is removed and `odd-active` is added you need to use `odd-active` instead of `odd`:

```
.odd-active .value-active { /*not .odd .value-active*/
width: 100%;
height: 25px;
line-height: 25px;
text-align: center;
color: #000000;
}
```